# Imágenes de Galería en bot para Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook

Buenas,
Estoy haciendo un bot para Facebook Messenger con Node.js y en él tengo una galería, ésta funciona correctamente, sin embargo, las imágenes no se ven correctamente debido a sus dimensiones. 
¿Es posible modificar el tamaño de la imagen de la plantilla genérica? Si no es posible, ¿Cómo sería posible simular este efecto desde mi código (imagen + botón como en la galería de Facebook Messenger).
La idea es poder mostrar una imagen ligeramente más alta que ancha, y por defecto la galería muestra las imágenes recortadas con el mismo ancho y alto.